Utimaco HSM simulator testing
Could you please help me with my understanding of the Utimaco HSM.
We are planning to store our keys in the Utimaco HSM.
what I have done is
downloaded the simulator (Utimaco SecurityServerEvaluation-V4.60.0.0)
I installed the simulator successfully, and along with that, I got some Java code for testing.
Now that I am trying to perform the crypto operations, i am trying to store my key without encryption, so i am using the importClearKey API to store my key. I am trying to convert my key string into a byte array and pass it to the importClearKey method.
Here, I am getting the
Exception in thread "main" CryptoServerAPI.CryptoServerException: CryptoServer Error B0680021
      CryptoServer module CXI
      invalid key size.

then I try to put the key into hashing using the following method:
byte[] aesKeyBytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(key.getBytes());
then I am able to store the key.
One thing is clear: the stored key can't be accessed from outside, so how can I use this key.
i have gone through some methods here, like
exportClearKey: What is the key, and what does the key type I have to pass here?
KEY_TYPE_PUBLIC
KEY_TYPE_PRIVATE
KEY_TYPE_SECRET
exportKey: What is the key type I should use?
KEY_TYPE_PUBLIC
KEY_TYPE_PRIVATE
KEY_TYPE_SECRET
I have tried, but all give some errors.
Crypt(): If I have to use this method, I need to pass the data in the byte format, but my actual key is stored in the HSM so how can i pass some data to encrypt.
findKey();
So which method do I have to use here, and what is the process I need to follow so that i can perform any cryptographic operations?
Can I get the proper documentation here so that i can get the step-by-step process here.
In simple language, what is the process to store the keys and how can I consume that stored key?
You can find the source code here.
SecurityServerEvaluation-V4.60.0.0/Documentation/Crypto_APIs/CXI_Java/html/class_crypto_server_c_x_i_1_1_crypto_server_c_x_i.html


... you do know that Utimaco offers training.  And you pointed to the documentation that you claim you don't have.  And there's example source code, in Java, for the exact steps you've described in the Crypto_APIs directory for both Java CXI and JCE.  And I'm trying to understand why you didn't just generate the key on the HSM and why you think you need to take it back out to use it.  But I'm still going to answer your questions, simply because that way, maybe others can benefit.

i am not thinking of take the keys back; instead, I am thinking how to refer to them, or consume them. i hope you are aware of the APIs inside Crypto_API and CXI_Java. could you please help me with what APIs i should use. and i have seen some of the training, but they are not in the near future. and a little expensive too.

in case it wasn't clear, I work for Utimaco.  I'm a principal member of technical staff, in fact.  so yeah, I know how the APIs work.  And I pointed you directly to the location of the answer to your question.  Did you look?

There is a complete example in Documentation/Crypto_APIs/CXI_Java, look for the "crypt" command, one of the overloads has the entire process from generating the key to encrypting and decrypting a payload as part of its comments.
And there is also source code supplied in the distribution, in the Crypto_APIs/CXI_Java/samples directory.  That will either be at the top of the installation (after installation) on Windows, or in the Software/Linux/x86_64/Crypto_APIs/CXI_Java/samples directory on Linux.
There is also source code examples for CXI for C++ (the native interface), JCE, as well as PKCS11 and a couple others.

can you please help me with the API. In order to store the keys, what is the API i have to use? Right now, I am using importClearKey().. and here we have some arguments about what i need to pass there. and after storing the keys. What is the API to consume the keys so that i can perform the remaining operations? The key storage will be done by other people, and the reuse of the same key will be done by other people in different time periods. So please help me with the architecture if you can. that would be a great help to me. I am expecting the APIs to understand more.

I could ask "which API do you want to use" but I do NOT want to go down that rat hole, because we are probably using "API" differently.  Utimaco has training, both self-paced and instructor led. My answer has everything needed to get started.  Don't ask open ended questions in stack overflow, and don't ask for free training.

CryptoServer module CXI,  invalid key size what is the ideal key size..?

Don't ask context-dependent, open-ended questions in stack overflow.
